# Not receiving error information from read data in firebase using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have managed to get firebase working and to read data from the database and present it.

I'm taking pictures and getting CoreML to work out what the item is then sending it to the database to return data on the item.

If the item is not in the database I, therefore want this to error but instead, the return is just blank. It seems like the firebase error block isn't working at all as it doesn't get to if after executing the first part of the code.

I have tried using a do catch block also but with no luck.

Please see the code attached:

```
    ref.child("items").child("\(self.final)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Get item value

    let value = snapshot.value as? String ?? ""
    print(value)
    self.calorieCount.text = "\(value)"


   }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("error")
        self.calorieCount.text = "Item not found, you will be able to add this soon"

}
}
```

Would somebody be able to tell me why the error part doesn't work when the item isn't in the database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having data at a location is not considered an error in the Firebase API, so the error closure doesn't get called. Instead your regular closure is called with an empty `DataSnapshot`, for which you can test with:

```
ref.child("items").child("\(self.final)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if !snapshot.exists() {
        self.calorieCount.text = "Item not found, you will be able to add this soon"
    }
    else {
        let value = snapshot.value as? String ?? ""
        self.calorieCount.text = "\(value)"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I played with so many different options and couldn't get anything to work, yet its so simple when you know how!

Comment: So was almost there, I just need to remove the ! before the snapshot.exists() and it worked!